# angularjs Datatables Cannot Reinitialize Table Error

Tags: jquery, angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

I am using angularjs Datatables and keep running into an error.

> DataTables Warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Cannot reinitialise Datatable.

I have two watches to run the report as the user changes input.

```
$scope.dtInstance = {};
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withPaginationType('full_numbers')
                                                    .withOption('responsive', true)
                                                    .withOption("autoWidth", false)
                                                    .withDOM('lfrtBip')
                                                    .withButtons(['copy', 'print', 'pdf', 'csv', 'excel']);


$scope.dtColumns = [
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('display_name').withTitle('Name'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('state_desc').withTitle('State'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('state_Type').withTitle('State Type'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('adjustedClientStartState').withTitle('State Start Date'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('adjustedClientEndState').withTitle('State End Date'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('timeInStateSeconds').withTitle('Seconds'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('timeInStateMinutes').withTitle('Minutes'),
    DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('timeInStateHour').withTitle('Hours'),
];

$scope.$watch('hours', function (newVal, oldVal)
{
    if (!newVal) return;

    runReport($scope.selectedClient.id, newVal);

});

$scope.$watch('selectedClient', function (newVal, oldVal)
{
    if (!newVal) return;

    runReport(newVal.id, $scope.hours);

});

var runReport = function (clientId, hours)
{
    if (clientId != 'undefined' && clientId != undefined)
    {
        ubernurseService.ClientStateHistory(clientId, hours).then(function (results)
        {


            $scope.states = results.data;

            if (results.data.length > 0)
            {
                $scope.notVisible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                $scope.notVisible = true;
            }
        }, function (error)
        {
            //alert(error.data.message);
        });
    }

}
```

And in my template

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <table datatable="ng" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" dt-instance="dtInstance" class="table table-hover table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                            <th>State Type</th>
                            <th>State Start Date</th>
                            <th>State End Date</th>
                            <th>Seconds</th>
                            <th>Minutes</th>
                            <th>Hours</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr ng-repeat="state in states">
                            <td>{{state.display_name}}</td>
                            <td>{{state.state_desc}}</td>
                            <td>{{state.state_Type}}</td>
                            <td>{{state.adjustedClientStartState | date:'medium'}}</td>
                            <td>{{state.adjustedClientEndState | date:'medium'}}</td>
                            <td>{{state.timeInStateSeconds}}</td>
                            <td>{{state.timeInStateMinutes}}</td>
                            <td>{{state.timeInStateHour}}</td>
                        </tr>

                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Can someone please shed some light onto what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: I know datatables but i don't know angular. You're trying to initialize a Datatable object with options on the same table element more than once. This is not allowed. I would look at the initialization code and figure out how it's being called more than once, and change that.

Comment: Good thoughts, its certainly was race condition as the two watch functions both make calls when the page is initially rendered.  You could also click the hour change button fast enough to overload the datatable rendering and cause it to happen that way as well.  I ended up using a bit of a hack to work around it.  Involved using three variables to identify if datatables was processing, if datatables was initialized, and to run the report initially when the page is loaded.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The error was because you were trying to reinitialize an existing database. What you need to include is `.withOption("destroy", true)` to:

```
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
```

That will resolve the issue.